# Overlapping tkinter elements

Tags: python, forms, tkinter, layout

I have a dictionary with some simple data like:

```
services = {
    'Colors': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Purple'],    
    'Animals': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Elephant', 'Giraffe', 'Kangaroo'],    
    'Fruits': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grapes', 'Watermelon'],
    'Countries': ['United States', 'Canada', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'France'],
    'Movies': ['Inception', 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Matrix', 'Pulp Fiction', 'Avatar'],
    'Planets': ['Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Neptune'],
    'Sports': ['Soccer', 'Basketball', 'Tennis', 'Golf', 'Swimming']
}
```

I'm trying to make a GUI with Tkinter to display this information, using a nested `for` loop to process the data, like so:

```
services_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Select Services")
services_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
services_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

services_vars = {}
row_counter = 0
columns_per_category = 3

for category, service_list in services.items():
    ttk.Label(services_frame, text=category).grid(row=row_counter, column=0, columnspan=columns_per_category * 2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
    row_counter += 1
    column_counter = 0
    max_rows = max(1, len(service_list) // columns_per_category + 1)
    for service in service_list:
        var = tk.IntVar()
        services_vars[service] = var
        checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(services_frame, text=service, variable=var)
        checkbox.grid(row=row_counter, column=column_counter, padx=5, pady=2, sticky="w")
        column_counter += 1
        if column_counter == columns_per_category:
            column_counter = 0
            row_counter += 1

# Add separators between categories
    ttk.Separator(services_frame, orient='horizontal').grid(row=row_counter, column=0, columnspan=columns_per_category * 2, sticky="ew")
    row_counter += 1
```

However, in the resulting GUI, the separators overlap some of the check boxes:

[image: Image of Tkinter UI]

I have tried many different things: padding, different rows, different configurations, but I cannot fix the problem.

How can I prevent the visual overlap?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I debug small programs?](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05). We do not write answers here that "find the bug" for you. Before suspecting a problem with Tkinter, I suggest that you should make sure that the code logic works as you expect - in particular, the calculation of the `row_counter` that will be used to create each `Separator`. It looks to me very clearly like they aren't just "overlapping", but are *in the same row* as the last row of checkboxes for each section (except when the number of options divides evenly into columns).

Comment: Please also keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. I [edit]ed the question to show how to explain problems clearly and **get to the point, without** talking about yourself, your level of experience or other things besides **the code**. (You don't even need to tell us that you run the code on a Mac; even if that matters to the problem, it's self-evident from the visual style in the screenshot.) For more information, please read [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/).

Comment: ...Yeah, on a closer read it's definitely a simple logic issue, of the sort that doesn't make a suitable Stack Overflow question. Think carefully about the `if column_counter == columns_per_category:` code, and what happens at the end of the `service_list`, if the number of elements doesn't divide in evenly.

Comment: Since you’re using `grid` you simply need to make sure each separator is on a separate row.

Comment: Thank you all for responses, I will look into that logic a little more in depth. Pointing out that they might actually be in the same row makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Overlapping tkinter elements.

> How can I prevent the visual overlap?

The problem can be fixed.

- On line 44 and 45, you had this:

  ttk.Separator(services_frame, orient='horizontal').grid(row=row_counter, column=0, columnspan=columns_per_category * 2, sticky="ew")
  row_counter += 1

Here is the separators overlap some of the check boxes:

[image]

To fix it to prevent overlap. Add  index on  line 44 and 45.

- On line 44, add parameter `+1` in `ttk.Separator(services_frame, orient='horizontal').grid(row=row_counter+1, ...)`
- On line 45,  add variable `+2` `row_counter += 2`

Here is result:

[image]